# Saving an Integer of type Int16 to Core Data - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, integer

I have a working app that saves a variety of different data points to Core Data. Every single item that saves to a String type field saves just find (I prove it out by fetching it afterwards and printing to screen). However, I'm having trouble with an integer field (Specifically the Int16 data type). Is there something wrong specifically with the line of code below trying to save the "activityOrder"?

```
    let newActivity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Activities", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject

    newActivity.setValue(selectedOwnerName, forKey: "activityOwner")
    newActivity.setValue(selectedActivityType, forKey: "activityType")
    newActivity.setValue(newNumber, forKey: "activityOrder")

    //save the record
    do {
        try newActivity.managedObjectContext?.save()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

I can confirm that the variable "newNumber" has a value, and is 1 in fact. the "activityOwner" and "activityType" fields save properly (again, they are all String type fields).

Here is the code I'm using to check if there is anything in there:

```
    let orderFetchRequest: NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Activities")
    orderFetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    orderFetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1

    do {
        let orderResults = try appDelegate.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(orderFetchRequest)
        orderData = orderResults as! [NSManagedObject]
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

    let orderSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "activityOrder", ascending: true)
    orderFetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [orderSortDescriptor]

    print(orderData)
```

Effectively I print our "orderData" which prints the entire record (which is where I see values for all String data but nil for the order)

I'm fairly new to Core Data and Swift. Do Integers behave differently from Strings when saving to Core Data?

Comment: how is `newNumber` declared in your managed object?

Comment: I originally declared it as var newNumber:Int, but I've also tried "NSNumber" "Int16" and others.

Comment: Can you include the code you're using to fetch the data and display it?

Comment: Sure thing @Michael, see the edits I've made.

Comment: Have you looked into the database to see what it is storing?

Comment: You've got your sort descriptor defined after the execute fetch request, and you're limiting the results to one record. Could it be that you're getting back a different record to the one you're expecting?

Comment: I haven't, but when I print my fetchResults, I essentially get what it's storying (if I'm not mistaken). When it prints, I get data for everything, except for that one "activityOrder" data field, which prints "nil"

Comment: The reason for the limit to one is I was trying to originally just pull the largest order number. Long story, but I'm trying to be able to order each item that I'm logging away to Core Data, and if I can't store an Int, I can't call it, and determine what the next variable should be stored as (i.e., max int + 1). Also, I don't think the order of the sort descriptor should impact it, but I'll check. Beyond that, the problem (I believe) is in the storing of the data, not the fetching of it.

Answer (score 0):

Core data could save only Object type. So if you want to dave Int type then convert it first into NSNumber object then save into Core Data.

```
let newActivity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Activities", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject
newActivity.setValue(selectedOwnerName, forKey: "activityOwner")
newActivity.setValue(selectedActivityType, forKey: "activityType")
newActivity.setValue(NSNumber(short: newNumber), forKey: "activityOrder")
```

Comment: So even with the addition of the NSNumber conversion, it still produces nil when I fetch the results.